# Is there a way to use a call from a SQL table to automatically generate an array of bound property questions for a html form with Razor pages?

Tags: c#, html, .net

I don't know if this is something you can do, but...

I have a Razor web page, and it has a form using the HTML `<form>` tags.

Right now I have each section and question hard coded into the application like this:

```
// Section One < -----
[BindProperty, Display(Name = "...")]
public string SectionOneQuestionOneAnswer { get; set; } = string.Empty;
[BindProperty, Display(Name = "...")]
public string SectionOneQuestionTwoAnswer { get; set; } = string.Empty;

// Section Two < -----
[BindProperty, Display(Name = "...")]
public string SectionTwoQuestionOneAnswer { get; set; } = string.Empty;
[BindProperty, Display(Name = "...")]
public string SectionTwoQuestionTwoAnswer { get; set; } = string.Empty;
[BindProperty, Display(Name = "...")]
public string SectionTwoQuestionThreeAnswer { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

This goes on for another four sections, and you can understand why I want to try and consolidate this.

I thought about doing something like this:

```cs
public class Question
{
    private string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string Prompt { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string Response { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private void SetId(string id) { Id = id; }
    private void SetPrompt(string prompt) { Prompt = prompt; }
    private void SetResponse(string response) { Response = response; }
    public string GetId() { return Id; }
    public string GetPrompt() { return Prompt; }
    public string GetResponse() { return Response; }
}

public class Section
{
    private Question[] Questions { get; set; } = Array.Empty<Question>();
    public Question[] GetQuestions() { return Questions; }
    public void AddQuestion(Question question) { Questions = Questions.Append(question).ToArray(); }
}
```

And call to a SQL table of 'Questions' to automatically generate an array of these "Sections" and "Questions" instead of hard-coding everything in.

Is there a way to do this?

This is how each Section in the HTML looks

```
<div class="container" id="section-0">
    <h3>
        Title
    </h3>
    <label class="form-control question-label border-0" asp-for="SectionFiveQuestionOneAnswer"></label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="SectionFiveQuestionOneAnswer"/>
    <label class="form-control question-label border-0" asp-for="SectionFiveQuestionTwoAnswer"></label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="SectionFiveQuestionTwoAnswer"/>
    <label class="form-control question-label border-0" asp-for="SectionFiveQuestionThreeAnswer"></label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="SectionFiveQuestionThreeAnswer"/>
</div>
```

I tried looking into custom model binding, and I was ending up very confused. I'm mainly a TypeScript developer, so C# is a bit of a new concept to me.